# How do you change a labels location in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to you put the label in the upper left corner?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('title')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry('800x500+200+100')
root.configure(background='black')
photo = PhotoImage(file='image.png')
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are several ways. The right way depends on other factors such as what other widgets will you have, and what you expect the widget to do if you resize the window. The answer could be very different if you have just a single label, or an entire complex GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have the one widget you can use pack or grid with arguments:

```
label.pack(anchor='nw')
```

or

```
label.grid(sticky='nw')
```

If you want to understand how you can build a GUI, I've got a lot out of [Thinking in Tkinter](http://thinkingtkinter.sourceforge.net/)

Then you will always have the helpful effbot pages: [The Tkinter Pack Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) and [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).